# Как почистить docker от неиспользуемых папок в версии 1.12.3?

Tags: docker

Используется версия docker 1.12.3

На диске занято очень много места. А как очистить те папки которые не привязаны к контейнерам и не используются?

```
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/b5/b5ef1b69bc3f0f31d4573c5d0f3a8ef7c1a9c6ecf27b65e0f062fa0673453dae
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/bc
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/bc/bc4ea50eb674e0a55c78c8f11a5a6974609840e20b5d4fafbb8b9e9ce7e1b29e
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/c4/c4d1caf39cb7d28783146ab4bdb5f5de22060a8804ec980e0eba4c0b26fbd050
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/c7/c70ee98a2f3a1bc8695ba04ed86cc47f4ea6148ac60244598531f465734e224e
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/c8/c8ac7062e7ee0cbff3e4e76b8ce05ad48a1649c218e2e8f8109b8dfc21c92580
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/d0/d099e777b723e68995a43f30e3d88768efa3cdbcfb7c10ea69ca75a98144d906
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/db/db898b86db048e94fdddc87015ee5bfa990301acd0df756e936543d2c38ca8c4
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e0/e091d9472d5e86506b5f6b0e5cd19edca13ef6da96692afe8bceb88a62037b4e
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e3/e3d745a14e20945836c5a8835544b747e78b93c5d5ffb80a5970f8a4f236364a
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e9/e91b67d9c27a49ab4f60980f7a9c205e7754a35e34fc18a738c6eb48db19f066
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ec/ec31fcfdb2fb3a46f264f202ee86057ae5814260723d3e5b1cfd2ab76b46cfdb
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ed/ed05625c9272d6dac0846ce3b44c6d54ec78bc27c237968b997a14f21bfa7171
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/f6/f6a92a48b60149e1dae0bf12d94b908d612af361cbc30084811b640dfa7069d2
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/fb/fbce7c778282fc3e3514bb11877b595c59a1a7238715702ceecab3606ab6c30e
291M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/fb/fbd499d92771ca4deb605ad74d526e352ad93ded8b5fba0b5b9576a192636cd3
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/26
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/53
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/6b/6b535473567adfa1a9bd15f200176f07890fe5b9659c9bb30bcbef12f58af39e
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/7b/7bfc543b0cba72b995ab7a7c4e98868a23b2714ae9db1e8328e1a5ff735d41ee
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/9d/9da5fc5474b37d252465e7c32bffaeb525f4fd10a92ac0fc475f2e697f55c00e
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/b2/b24bcda479ce0285ae2b00b36f3ee6944d34d545a2ecdd000de467b5a79602b0
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/cc/cc1ae156e244f7ebf9e14440b28c15619799be3e2a3febac0fc654bc6e63877e
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/e0/e007acf06b89c04d735db67a767872e9894e7bdd65e6adad11cd60113a614050
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/ea/eaad5d518fd697a69194a59e4baf87c9c7351aabcf1a00d71086ed50128e463f
292M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/f0/f026779fdbc2a56ac5ef4f4ab9d8310f49b7258db2345ca3d90afa86370c023e
293M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/04/047338d364267ad122431b1c0ed47ce33701a9c32083bf51ac2ee030d8e8804d
293M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/0a/0a3da3e2fbe4ac3b5c7fede3f7130baf4fe1ef441eb2d5e894dc8f634afec1b4
293M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/45/454cb626f33b6a5d87d800e647158a304d4817b65b237bd10db00ed3b9c17d6b
293M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/47/473e5e762441ac4f94cb616b74d40bb0875c439559f0fd2f296d99639511705c
293M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/4b/4be0ce4dec42f49eab0133ba0ff211ef8cdb4f0d15ec826d96c728d50fafec08
293M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/65/65adb6d14ad1afbae1dd7d85003875e4e8202a1ab7660c0c4ebf3e769a641ac1
293M    /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/6b/6b4241619dd091cc0e6b941077510137cc1284c9fdc4053c30c08232e1ee260d
```

Comment: Что за древняя версия докера? Актуальная 18! А так, `docker container prune`, `docker image prune`, `docker network prune`, `docker volume prune`. Или все сразу `docker system prune`

Comment: docker container prune

Пишет
docker: 'container' is not a docker command.

Comment: `docker --version` какую версию выдает? 1.12.3? Это очень старая версия. Тогда `docker images | grep "<none>" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi`

Comment: Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec

Comment: `docker images | grep "<none>" | awk '{print $3}' | xargs docker rmi`

Comment: Образы так удаляются. Но еще что то остаётся неочищенным. 
Вот в этих папках 100gb лежит. 
/data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/

Comment: Не могу помочь, слишком древний докер, на новом совершенно другая структура каталогов. Можно `ls -la /data/registry/data/docker/registry/v2/blobs/sha256/b5/b5ef1b69bc3f0f31d4573c5d0f3a8ef7c1a9c6ecf27b65e0f062fa0673453dae` посмотреть что там. Вдруг какой-нибудь `config.v2.json`, от этого и плясать. Либо обновиться до версии 1.13, кажется там появилась `docker ... prune`